# Doctrine query returns extra field in result

Tags: mysql, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

I have a Doctrine query;

```
    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()->select('s.monthly_volume')
    ->from('SearchVolume s')
    ->innerJoin('s.Keywords k')
    ->where('k.group_id = ?',array($group_id));
```

I just want it to return the monthly_volume value in the result array. It currently returns monthly_volume and id, I don't want it to return the id in result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine automatically adds the primary key field to the results in almost every type of hydration mode.

In a case like this where you want a simple array and only have a single field being selected, the answer is the Single Scalar Hydration mode.  Use it like this:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()->select('s.monthly_volume')
    ->from('SearchVolume s')
    ->innerJoin('s.Keywords k')
    ->where('k.group_id = ?');

$monthly_volumes = $q->execute(array($group_id), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_SINGLE_SCALAR);
```

You should find that $monthly_volumes is a simple one-dimensional array containing only the value(s) you wanted.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks Jweible.

Comment: @Sid Glad I could help.  I had to solve the same problem myself not too long ago.

Comment: And with a query that return multiples values, how can I get a one-dimensional array only with the values?